# Doctrine DQL query get all records with ManyToMany relation

Tags: doctrine, dql

For an optimized query with Doctrine in a Symfony 3 project, I want to select multiple entities like this :

Entity "e" have a oneToMany relation and "a" have also a OneToMany relation with "au" ("au" should have been the linked table in a ManyToMany relation but i needed some extra fields in it)

```
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('e');

    return $qb->select('e, d, du')
             ->leftJoin('e.demos', 'd')
             ->leftJoin('d.demo_user', 'du')
             ->getQuery()
             ->getResult();
```

If one of my relation is empty (there is no demo_user for exemple), my entity e and related are not send in results. I want to have ALL the results even if there is no demo nor demo_user related.

Thank you for your help ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Example to connect 3 entities in query:

you must link table in query

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder( 'e' ) 
    // if skip "->select ..." then receive all column form entities: E, AU, DU
    ->select(
        'e.id as id',
        'e.taskName as taskName',
            'e.dueDate as dueDate',
            'au.isOwn as isOwn',
            'du.fild2 as fild2'
        )
        ->leftJoin('YourBundle:EntityAU', 'au', 'WITH', 'au.idTask = e.id')
        ->leftJoin('YourBundle:EntityDU', 'du', 'WITH', 'ad.fild1 = au.id')
        ->where( 'au.idParent = :par1' )
        ->setParameter( 'par1', $varId )
        ->orderBy( 't.parentString', 'ASC' )
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```